# Is there a way to execute initializer code before each test in Visual Studio Unit Testing (MSTest) for all tests in a project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest

I have a Unit Test project with 20+ .cs files.  I want to run some setup code before each individual test.  Kinda like how the [TestInitialize] attribute works.  However, I'd need to put that attribute on all 20+ of my .cs files.

Is there a way to centralize the initializing code in one place for every test in my entire project?

Thanks!

-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike the only bootstrapping hooks are [ClassInitialize] and [TestInitialize] and their teardown counterparts.  In cases like these I just externalized the common logic into its own class, essentially follow normal DRY and SoC practices.  Typically I have several services and providers defined within my test assemblies and the xInitialize methods just have 1 or 2 lines of code to call the approperiate provider.  That being said mpistrich's answer is perfectly acceptable as well, I perfer layering over inheritence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is still an issue. But I found one more solution do achieve this: 
When opening the .testsettings file, go to the "Setup and Cleanup scripts" tab, you can specify scripts to run before and after the tests run.